# Testing a pointer for nil or assigned causes Access Violation

Tags: object, delphi, null

I have encountered a rare situation where testing for a Delphi object pointer <> nil causes an access violation.  Could I understand what are the possible circumstances that may cause this issue?  I had previously thought that testing for NIL would never cause Access Violations.

Delphi 10.4.1 with Firemonkey.

```
private
  FAni: FAniIndicator;  { it is a pointer to a TAniIndicator created elsewhere }
public
end;

in some code

try
  if FAni = nil then
    showmessage('FAni=nil')
  else
    showmessage('FAni<>nil');
except
   showmessage('ERROR occurs here for just testing = NIL');
end;
```

Comment: Merely `Free`ing a previously allocated pointer is insufficient to prevent an AV occurring when referencing it.  This q requires a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to avoid needless speculation about the cause.

Comment: Indeed, you have a bug in your code, but it is not the `FAni = nil` test.

Comment: just to clarify, so there is some illegal operation on FAni prior to me testing for FAni=nil but that the A.V. only show up later when I'm testing for FAni ?

Comment: The problem need not even be related to the `FAni` field in particular. (In fact, it almost surely isn't.)

Comment: @Peter guaranteed that the problem cannot be with what you have done to FAni. Problem is outside the class.

Comment: Thank you for all the pointers.  It is indeed a wrong/invalid pointer to the class instance that contains the FAni... which strangely when referencing the class instance, does not produce A.V. immediately and still continue to run a few lines in the code, until it randomly exploded with a A.V. somewhere.

Comment: @PeterJones welcome to the wide fun world of *undefined behavior*.

Comment: At least now I know an invalid pointer to a class instance may not produce an A.V. immediately.  Thanks to all for the pointers, no pun intended.

Answer (score 1):

The object reference on which you called this method is invalid. Were it a valid reference then this code could not result in an Access Violation. Therefore, it cannot be a valid reference.

Look at the code which calls this method, and debug to find out why the object reference is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

The code shown is inside of a class method. Which means the code is actually testing `Self.FAni` for nil. For that to crash with an AV means that `Self` itself is not pointing at a valid object.

In other words, this method is being called via an invalid object pointer. Maybe the object was freed beforehand. Maybe the pointer is unassigned. Maybe memory has been corrupted. We can't see what is actually happening from your limited example. You will have to debug this for yourself.